# fixed div, content fixed but background-image not

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble creating a fixed div on top of my webpage. This is what I have :

```
<header id="headerCntr">
    <div id="headcont">
        <!--  / language box \ -->
        <article class="languageBox">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="/nl">NL</a></li>
                <li><a href="/en">EN</a></li>
            </ul>

        </article>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <a href="/nl/" class="logo">front.text.seotitlemuseeuwbikes</a>

        <article class="searchBox">

            <form>
                <dl class="zend_form">

                    <dd>
                        <input>
                    </dd>

                    <dd>

                        <input id="element1" class="button" type="button" value="submit">

                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </form>

        </article>

        <nav class="menuBox">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/fietsen">Fietsen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/technologie">technologie</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/over-museeuwbikes">Over ons</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/service">service</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/planet-museeuw">Planet museeuw</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/nieuws">nieuws</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/nl/partners">partners</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#headerCntr {
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    top:0; 
    background: 
    url('../images/header-960.png') top left repeat-y; 
    height:150px;
}
#headcont{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1200px;
}
```

My content is always on top, but the background-image not .. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: When I scroll down the header should always be fixed on my top of screen..

Comment: no need for the background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: the there is something else wrong with your code, pls create a fiddle, else is there no way of telling you what the problem is.
Show us the live website pls

Comment: what do you exactly want? If you only want to align your image to top, then try this: `url('../images/header-960.png') 0 0 no-repeat; `

Comment: When I scroll down the header should always be fixed on my top of screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with adding `position:fixed;` to your `#headcont`